# How to pull specific values from ansible facts

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine

New to ansible, learning how to work with returned data from a task. I am trying to pull the IP address from the following returned data (this is a snippit):

```
"vmfacts": {
  "changed": false, 
  "failed": false, 
  "virtual_machines": {
      "Alpha-0": {
          "cluster": "GPLAB-Compute01", 
          "esxi_hostname": "gplab-esxi02.gplab.com", 
          "guest_fullname": "Other Linux (64-bit)", 
          "ip_address": "192.168.0.1",
```

If I run

```
- debug:
    var: vmfacts.virtual_machines
```

I get the full dictionary of VMs, which is all fine. But how would I get the IP address for the Alpha-0 VM? I've tried multiple variations to pull the value but I can't seem to get it. I'm sure it is simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to address sub-keys in nested dictionaries. As you have found, it is possible to reference a sub-key by separating each key with dots. This however is effectively shorthand, and there are various cases where it will not work.

I am guessing you have tried the dots method, and are running into problems because 'Alpha-0' contains a '-', which is a significant char in YAML, used to identify a list item.

The long form version is to wrap each key with `['']` (you don't need the single quotes if you are using a variable containing the name of the key), so in your case, this should work:

```
- debug:
    var: vmfacts['virtual_machines']['Alpha-0']['ip_address']
```